# seo friendly url not working in my website

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, blogs

this link(http://pickmyoffers.com/searched?q=Flipkart) what i want to change as SEO friendly http://pickmyoffers.com/searched/q/Flipkart or http://pickmyoffers.com/searched/Flipkart

But i can't able to change it on htaccess

my code is below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^q/([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)$ ./searched.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^q/([a-z]*)$ ./searched.php?q=$1
```

i don't know what is this do i just copy this from website

Comment: Why are you trying to use a bridging cast?

Comment: Why are you even using a cast?

Comment: thanks for your replay i solve this problem

Comment: just remove the (__bridge NSString *)